# Export a reveal.js presentation to LibreOffice (odp) or PowerPoint (ppt, pptx)

Tags: powerpoint, libreoffice, reveal.js

How do I export a reveal.js presentation to LibreOffice (`*.odp`) or PowerPoint (`*.ppt`, `*.pptx`)?

It's fairly easy to export to PDF, but for my colleague's to reuse my slides (and mix them with their own), they need ODP or PPT. I will always stick with html slides (such as reveals.js) because it is git friendly.

Comment: I recommend to write the presentation in Markdown and then process it with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) into both reveal.js and PowerPoint, as well as other formats. Also have a look at [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) as a usability wrapper for Pandoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Word 2013 can now edit PDF, so can LibreOffice Draw.

I'd try what happens if you open the PDF in either of these and then try to get to save as PPTX / ODP.

Comment: I got it to work like this: export to PDF, open the PDF with LibreOffice (which will open Draw), select all slides and copy-paste them into a new LibreOffice Impress document. There is a noticeable quality loss, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after you export to PDF, you can import a PDF file at the Power Point.

You can import a PDF file as a picture or as an object, just follow [this steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-PDF-file-content-into-a-PowerPoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62) to import.

I Hope that helps!

Comment: It seems this won't transform the 500 individual PDF slides into 500 powerpoint slides, as it will just embed a PDF link. So it's impossible for my colleague's to remove slides and mix it with their own.

I wouldn't mind that the individual slides are just screenshot images (if I don't have to extract them manually - my slides change a lot), but each slide should be a separate in powerpoint too.